# NavigationService blocks

Tags: navigation

within my main window, i use following code to navigate to a page.

```
 private void logThresholds_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(trainSetQualityPage);
            trainSetQualityPage.MeasureQuality();
        }
```

the page will be shown after the processing of the method measure quality (takes a couple of seconds), but that should be avoided.
a progressbar is included within the page trainsetquality, but it will be shown at the end as described above.

therefore, what can be changed that the user interface changes the view without a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading about NavigationService, i tried the Navigated event which did not the trick.

subsequent, [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) was applied and the user interface can be used during processing of my stuff. according to msdn, `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged` events are used.

only a minor obstacle - a try catch was relevant for the `ReportProgress` method because it throws twice an exception.